# Java - Having AND and OR in the same condition, without parentheses

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I know that using And (&&) and OR (||) in a condition statement shouldn't be used without parentheses.

So if you should use both conditions you should do `(A && !B) || (C && D)`

However, in some code I saw that they are not using Parentheses? What would happen then? I thought that didn't compile:

```
A && !B || C && D
```

I guess that it would resolve as with SUMS or MULTIPLICATIONS, I mean, resolve them as they are read:

```
(((A && !B) || C) && D)
```

Comment: There's an order of operations for all symbols: +, *, &, ||, etc., as there woiuld have to be: see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) But when in doubt or to ensure clarity, parentheses are a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And (`&&`) has precedence over or (`||`) in the [order of operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). So, this

```
A && !B || C && D
```

Is entirely equivalent to

```
(A && !B) || (C && D)
```

Comment: And since `!` has precedence over both `&&` and `||`, it's also equivalent to `(A && (!B)) || (C && D)`.